# how to set openweather api tiles to openstreet map in android?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, tile, openweathermap

I'm not able to set openweather api tiles on openstreet map, I don't want to use google map if any other map available outside google map please suggest.

I want to load different types of openweather api tiles on my map but I don't want to use google map.

Comment: Please mention the library / framework this question is about. OpenStreetMap is just raw data but not something you could add tiles to.

Comment: Cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/87099/openweather-api-tiles